# why the size of a class and its object are always same

Tags: c++

I created a virtual destructor which creates a virtual table for the base class.  I am fine with the extra size created for the object by virtual pointer but don't know why size of class also increases.

Does creating of virtual table have any impact on size of base class??

Please check

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class xxx{
        int  x;
        char j;
public:
 virtual ~xxx()
 {
   cout<<"destructor"<<endll    
 }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  xxx x1;
  cout<<"sizeof class="<<sizeof(xxx)<<endl;

  cout<<"size of object="<<sizeof(x1)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If they were different, how would you know how much memory to allocate to hold an instance of a class?

Comment: Can you elaborate, why would you expect something else? Uhhm _vtable_, _base class_ what?

Comment: @nos: Backwards: `sizeof (typexxx)` means "what is the size of an instance of `typexxx`".  There's no way to find the size of a type, whatever that means (I guess it should include static member variables, code for the member functions, the vtable, the `type_info` object that provides runtime type information, etc)

Answer (score 4):

There are two forms of `sizeof` operator invocation:

```
sizeof( type )      
sizeof expression
```

The former returns size of instance of *type*, whereas the latter returns size of an object which type would be returned by `expression`. In particular, given object `x1` of type `xxx`, `sizeof(xxx)` and `sizeof x1` must return the same value. So, you are not comparing "object size" versus "class size".

In C++, there is no concept of "class size". You could try to estimate it by adding vtable size and sum of sizes of static members, but language itself doesn't provide any handy tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the class increases because (on most modern compilers - always got to add that disclaimer to calm the purists) the structure now includes a pointer to an array of vtables at the front.

That vtable pointer gets carried around with the object.